# MPI_Gather for 2D vectors

Tags: c++, mpi, 2d-vector

I have seen answers on MPI gather for 2d arrays but not too much for  2D std::vectors. Each process has its 2d vector called border_matrix of shape 3 x 5. The objective is to MPI_Gather into global_border_matrix at the root process in such a way that each border matrix is stacked on top of each other. In this case, the shape would be 9 x 5 because of 3 processes including the root. Here is a small abstraction of my problem from a bigger codebase. This breaks at the point of MPI gather.

```
vector<vector<int>> global_border_matrix;
vector<vector<int>> border_matrix;

height=3;
width=5;
num_partitions=3;

//---
//Fill in data for border_matrix. All of them are of same shape
//---
if(rank == root)
   global_border_matrix.resize(height * num_partitions);

MPI_Gather(border_matrix.data(),  height, MPI_INT, 
           global_border_matrix.data(), height, MPI_INT, 
           root, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

As a bonus question, how would this work for variable sized vectors. For now, I am keeping the size of all border matrices constant by padding it with 0s but that adds a lot of latency for bigger problem sizes. Ideally, I would like to send vectors of random shapes and the root process somehow stacks them on top of each other.

Comment: long story short, you can't use jagged arrays with MPI.

Comment: Not impossible, just extremely cumbersome. And it will involve gathering the sizes of the individual component vectors first. Depending on the network characteristics, it may actually be slower than simply padding the arrays.

Comment: ok, let me rephase it: "don't use jagged arrays with MPI"